# How to install react-native-track-player

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-track-player

I tried to install the react-native-track-player in a bare (just react-native init) App.

After

```
yarn add react-native-track-player
yarn add react-native-swift
cd ios
pod instal
```

I got the message:

- [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "react-native-track-player":
  In Podfile:
  react-native-track-player (from `../node_modules/react-native-track-player`)
  Specs satisfying the `react-native-track-player (from` ../node_modules/react-native-track-player`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

So I changed in the podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0' to: platform :ios, '10.0'
```

and again

```
pod install
```

This results to the message:

- [!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:
  `react-native-track-player` does not specify a Swift version and none of the targets (`mist`) integrating it have the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute set. Please contact the author or set the `SWIFT_VERSION` attribute in at least one of the targets that integrate this pod.

In the next step I added  s.swift_version = '4.0' to the react-native-track-player.podspec file in the node_modules.

Now the react-native-track-player pod were generated with the warnings:

- [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

```
PBXBuildFile -- Pods.xcodeproj/targets/buildConfigurationList:buildConfigurations:baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,defaultConfigurationIsVisible:0,defaultConfigurationName:Release,displayName:ConfigurationList,isa:XCConfigurationList,,buildPhases:buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Headers,files:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,isa:PBXHeadersBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,,buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Sources,files:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,isa:PBXSourcesBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,,buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Frameworks,files:,isa:PBXFrameworksBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,,buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Copy generated compatibility header,files:,inputFileListPaths:,inputPaths:|,|,|,isa:PBXShellScriptBuildPhase,name:Copy generated compatibility header,outputFileListPaths:,outputPaths:|,|,|,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,shellPath:/bin/sh,shellScript:COMPATIBILITY_HEADER_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/Swift Compatibility Header/${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}-Swift.h"
MODULE_MAP_PATH="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}.modulemap"
ditto "${DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR}/${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}-Swift.h" "${COMPATIBILITY_HEADER_PATH}"
ditto "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/react_native_track_player/react-native-track-player.modulemap" "${MODULE_MAP_PATH}"
ditto "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/react_native_track_player/react-native-track-player-umbrella.h" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}"
printf "\n\nmodule ${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}.Swift {\n  header \"${COMPATIBILITY_HEADER_PATH}\"\n  requires objc\n}\n" >> "${MODULE_MAP_PATH}"
,,buildRules:,dependencies:displayName:React,isa:PBXTargetDependency,,displayName:react-native-track-player,isa:PBXNativeTarget,name:react-native-track-player,packageProductDependencies:,productName:react-native-track-player,productReference:displayName:libreact-native-track-player.a,explicitFileType:archive.ar,includeInIndex:0,isa:PBXFileReference,name:libreact-native-track-player.a,path:libreact-native-track-player.a,sourceTree:BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,,productType:com.apple.product-type.l  ............
```

So I added "install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false" to the podfile

Now pod install runs without warnings, but the build in xcode or react-native run-ios crashes with the error

- Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

This is my configuration:

```
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.3
CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8500B CPU @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 68.81 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 13.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 28, 29
Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.3
System Images: android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.6 AI-192.7142.36.36.6200805
Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: ^16.12.0 => 16.12.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

and the packages.json file

```
{
  "name": "first",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-swift": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-track-player": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

and the ios/podfile

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
use_frameworks!

target 'neu' do
  # Pods for neu
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'neuTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'neu-tvOS' do
  # Pods for neu-tvOS

  target 'neu-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I am stranded! Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Would you please share the Podfile?

Comment: podfile is above

Comment: Would you please add `use_frameworks!` after the this line `platform :ios, '10.0'`?

Comment: With use_frameworks!: build error is the same: Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code. I updated the podfile

Comment: Try with update "platform :ios, '11.0'"

Answer (score 4):

For React Native versions `>0.60` follow the additional installation instructions in the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player/blob/dev/docs/Installation.md#install-react-native-swift):

After running `yarn add react-native-track-player` do the following:

1. Run `pod install` in the `/ios` folder.
2. Add the `react-native-swift` package e.g. via `yarn add react-native-swift`
3. Run `react-native swiftify`.

These additional steps have to be done because the iOS part of the module was written in Swift and not in Objective-C. And React Native does not support bridging modules written in Swift out of the box.

But no other manual steps are necessary for React Native versions greater than `0.60`.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After steps from documentation for react-native-track-player 2, I v got error *"Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `SwiftAudioEx (0.14.2)`"*
What I did

1. Go to the **Xcode** -> **File** -> **Add Packages** [image]

2)Find **SwiftAudioEx** package , in **Dependency Rule** chose --> **Exact Version** and **Add to Project** -> Pods[image]
3) Build Project via Xcode or npx react-native run-ins

Answer (score 0):

**I install the @next (^2.2.0-rc3) version and works fine**

> "react-native-track-player": "^2.2.0-rc3"

Follow this command

```
npm install --save react-native-track-player@next
```